# Renderizar dados JSON recebidos de uma API em uma Tabela HTML/Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-templates

Amigos, preciso da ajuda de vocês!

Sou novo com Python/Django e estou fazendo esse projeto com o conhecimento que adquiro no dia-a-dia estudando.

Eu tenho uma função na minha views.py que se comunica com uma API e trás um resultado em Json. O resultado é basicamente esse:

```
[
{
    "_id": "5d6f28ec02523e0012a4eae6",
    "repasse": false,
    "renderSatisfacao": false,
    "botTimeOut": false,
    "ignore": false,
    "sair": false,
    "erroslog": [],
    "chaterroslog": [],
    "Historico": [],
    "userID": "5b43b8a48b769470363b58909a9049",
    "usuario_key": "ABCD",
    "usuario_nome": "Igor Miranda",
    "Created_at": "2019-09-04T03:01:00.716Z",
    "__v": 0
},
{
    "_id": "5d6f291d55d3f500402d338e",
    "repasse": false,
    "renderSatisfacao": false,
    "botTimeOut": false,
    "ignore": false,
    "sair": false,
    "erroslog": [],
    "chaterroslog": [],
    "Historico": [],
    "userID": "577a55a043aab2a6aa78586b2520392",
    "usuario_key": "ABCD",
    "usuario_nome": "Igor Miranda",
    "Created_at": "2019-09-04T03:01:49.484Z",
    "__v": 0
},
]
```

Eu preciso renderizar esse resultado dentro de uma tabela em uma página HTML com o Django, onde eu tenho o resultado dos campos "usuario_nome", "usuario_key" e "Historico".

Eu já li vários tópicos aqui no StackOverFlow, mas ainda não consegui resolver a minha necessidade.

Segue os meus arquivos views.py, ConsumirApi.html e o resultado na página.

views.py

```
def ConsumirApi(request):
    url = 'http://urlapi.test.com.br'
    body = {"start" : "2019-09-04 19:30:00", "end" : "2019-09-04 23:59:59"}
    response = requests.post(url, auth=HTTPBasicAuth('123456', 'password1234'), 
    headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, json=body)
    resultado = json.loads(response.content)

    resultado_saida = [{k:v for k,v in x.items() if k in ["Historico", "usuario_nome", "usuario_key"]} for x in resultado]
    drop_falsey = lambda path, key, value: bool(value)
    clean = remap(resultado_saida, visit=drop_falsey)
    resultadofinal = json.dumps(clean, indent=4, sort_keys=True)

    return TemplateResponse(request, 'ConsumirApi.html', { "resultadofinal": resultadofinal })
```

ConsumirApi.html

```
<table id="test_table" class="display table table-striped table-bordered" border="1" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>usuario_nome</th>
        <th>usuario_key</th>
        <th>Historico</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>     
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    var json={{ response.content | safe }}

    $('#test_table').DataTable({
        resultadofinal : json.resultadofinal ,   //get the array of object data
        "columns":[
        {"resultadofinal ": "usuario_key"},
        {"resultadofinal ": "usuario_nome"},
        {"resultadofinal ": "Historico"}]
        });
    });  
</script>
```

Resultado obtido até o momento:
[image: Resultado obtido até o momento:]
Alguém poderia me ajudar a identificar aonde estou errando ou se está faltando algo? Li em alguns tópicos que algumas pessoas utilizam funções dentro do arquivo models.py, mas eu não tenho nada dentro desse arquivo, é realmente necessário ter algo nele?

Answer (score 1):

Vamos lá, pelo o que eu vi você quer só consultar resultados, então a requisição seria um GET e não um POST como você colocou:

```
response = requests.post(url, auth=HTTPBasicAuth('123456', 'password1234'),
```

Outra coisa, se é só mostrar os dados em uma tabela vc pode fazer isso utilizando o próprio template do Django, sem precisar de script JS. Segue um exemplo que eu fiz:

Exemplo de retorno do meu JSON:

```
[
    {
        "id": 265,
        "nome": "ARM Vergalhão 10,0 (3/8) SOB MEDIDA",
        "estoque_min": 0,
        "estoque": 0
    },
    {
        "id": 262,
        "nome": "ARM Vergalhão 10,0 (3/8) SOB MEDIDA C/ AMARR",
        "estoque_min": 0,
        "estoque": 0
    },
    {
        "id": 224,
        "nome": "ARM Vergalhão 12,5 (1/2)",
        "estoque_min": 0,
        "estoque": 0
    }
]
```

Views:

```
def json_teste(request):
    url = 'SUA_URL_API_AQUI'
    headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    response = json.loads(response.content)

    resultado = response

    context = {}
    context['resultado'] = resultado

return render(request, 'api.html', context)
```

api.html

```
<table id="test_table" class="display table table-striped table-bordered" border="1" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Item</th>
        <th>Estoque Min</th>
        <th>Estoque</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
        {% for r in resultado %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ r.id }}</td>
            <td>{{ r.nome }}</td>
            <td>{{ r.estoque_min }}</td>
            <td>{{ r.estoque }}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
</tbody>
        <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Item</th>
            <th>Estoque Min</th>
            <th>Estoque</th>
        </tr>
        </tfoot>
</table>
```

Resultado:

[image: Resultado final]